# Spring batch : Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-batch

I just started learning spring batch with no prior experience of Spring batch.

I downloaded a template from start.spring.io and selected following

[image]

After this I imported the project in IntelliJ IDE and made following changes

Added a job configuration class:

```
package io.spring.helloworld.configuration;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration  //For spring configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing  //bootstrap all the infra needed to run spring batch
public class jobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;


    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Hello World");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job HelloWorld() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("HelloWorldJob")
                .start(step1())
                .build();


    }

}
```

and this is how my entry class looks

```
package io.spring.helloworld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication

public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I have not touched or modified any class\configuration. But when i run the app,  I get following message:

```
Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

What Can i do to fix this error?

Comment: Well, what kind of database do you want? Embedded or external? Have you checked google? I tried "supported spring-batch embedded databases", and I got [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch12s08.html). Which lists HSQL, H2 and Derby as being supported.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error there are two methods:

Method 1:

Try adding below annotation:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class HelloWorldApplication {
-----
}
```

Method 2:

you can add the below line in `application.properties` file

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```